# Gemming for Blood dk to tank Firelands normal/heroic

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is it better to gem for Stamina, Mastery, Dodge or Parry?

- Stamina for blue sockets?
- Parry + mastery for red/yellow?
- Full stamina for more vengeance and bigger blood shields?
- Stamina + mastery as much as I can with still getting socket bonuses?
- Or dodge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dodge and Parry should be around 15% because getting more would be a waste of rating. (You get less % per point rating as the % goes up and 15% is the "breakpoint" of effectivness, so getting more wont be as beneficial as other stats)

That means when you got 15% Parry and 15% dodge go for mastery and stamina.

Comment: What about trinkets, mastery or stamina?

Comment: AFAIK you should go with "Scales of life" (nice sta boost and nice healing if used) and "Spidersilk Spindle". Our DK Tank told me those 2 are BiS for Blood Dk.

Answer (score 0):

As a Blood Dk your number one stat is Mastery. So gem wise I would use Pussiant Dream Emerald, 20 to mastery and 30 to stamina, Fine ember topaz, 20 to Parry and 20 to mastery, and Fractured Amberjewel 40 to mastery. Gem this way and your DPS will praise you! You wont be able to reach the "unhittable" threshold with the 4.2 patch but you can come close. I wont get into diminishing returns because that is another discussion all on its own. Mastery>Dodge>Parry best way to look at it.  Good Luck